# Python - Using regex to write a function imitating the strip() method

Tags: python, regex

I am doing a problem from Automate the Boring Stuff, trying to imitate the strip() method using regex. I have pretty much figured it out, works with whitespace and a specific word I want removed. But when removing a specific keyword from the end of a string, it always cuts the last letter of the string off, can anyone help me figure out why?

```
def strip_func(string, *args):
strip_regex = re.compile(r'^(\s+)(.*?)(\s+)$')
mo = strip_regex.findall(string)
if not mo:
    rem = args[0]
    remove_regex = re.compile(rf'({rem})+(.*)[^{rem}]')
    remove_mo = remove_regex.findall(string)
    print(remove_mo[0][1])

else:
    print(mo[0][1])
```

So if no second argument is passed then the function deletes whitespace from either side of the string, 
I used this string to test that:

```
s = '        This is a string with whitespace on either side        '
```

Otherwise it deletes the keyword, kind of like the strip function. Eg:

```
spam = 'SpamSpamBaconSpamEggsSpamSpam'
strip_func(spam, 'Spam')
```

Output:

```
BaconSpamEgg
```

So missing the 's' at the end of Eggs, same thing happens with every string I try. Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: `rf'({rem})+(.*)[^{rem}]'` is just wrong, you cannot negate a sequence of chars with a negated character class. Use `rf'({rem})+(.*?)(?={rem}|$)'`

Comment: I suspect all you need is `def strip_func(string, *args):
  return re.sub(rf'^(?:{re.escape(args[0])})+(.*?)(?:{re.escape(args[0])})+$', r'\1', string, flags=re.S)
    `. See https://ideone.com/6jHH68

Comment: Am I right all you need is to remove consecutive multicharacter sequences at the start and end of string?

Comment: Thanks! I thought the negated character class sequence was weird but it was the closest I got, so just went with it. Ya I want to remove the consecutive sequences from the start and end. Your update works well, so thanks again.

Comment: Done, thank you for the step by step explanation as well :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

def strip_func(string, *args):
  return re.sub(rf'^(?:{re.escape(args[0])})+(.*?)(?:{re.escape(args[0])})+$', r'\1', string, flags=re.S)

spam = 'SpamSpamBaconSpamEggsSpamSpam'
print(strip_func(spam, 'Spam'))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/6jHH68). The `^(?:{re.escape(args[0])})+(.*?)(?:{re.escape(args[0])})+$` pattern will create a pattern like `^(?:Spam)+(.*?)(?:Spam)+$` and will match

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:Spam)+` - one or more occurrences of `Spam` at the start of the string
- `(.*?)` - Group 1: any 0 or more chars as few as possible
- `(?:Spam)+` - one or more occurrences of `Spam` at the start of the string
- `$` - end of string.

The `flags=re.S` will make `.` match line break chars, too.